# QTMovie can't play any video

Tags: macos

I'm having a problem of playing video from QTMovie and Quicktime movie view. Here is my code:
"AppController.h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
@interface AppController : NSObject
{

    IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet QTMovieView *movie;
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender;
@end
```

"AppController.m"

```
#import "AppController.h"
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
@implementation AppController
@synthesize movie;
- (void)play:(id)sender

{

    [label setStringValue:@"play"];

    NSURL *url3=[NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://218.204.223.237:554/live/1/66251FC11353191F/e7ooqwcfbqjoo80j.sdp"];    

    NSError* error = nil;

    NSString *path=@"/Users/shenashley/Movies/cookie.mpg";   

    QTMovie* qtm = [QTMovie movieWithURL: url2 error:&error];   

    if(qtm != nil)

    {

        [movie setMovie:qtm];

        [movie play:self];

    }

    else

    {

        NSLog(@"Error loading movie: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }   

}
@end
```

I already tried t play both local file and url. both are fail. with the local mpg file I played, I can heard the sound but the screen is black. and with the url (which I have tried many different url). never work. it's always black screen and nothing show up.

when I click play. it show a warning:
"** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead."

is it a bug in sdk10.8?

Is there any other framwork that can play rtsp or m3u8 stream that I can replace QTKit?

I upload my project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1904isjkkhxecj2/NewOSX.zip

hope somebody can help me!!! I already stuck in here for a while. REALLY NEED HELP!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the movie state:

```
long state = [[movie attributeForKey:QTMovieLoadStateAttribute] longValue];
if(state != QTMovieLoadStateComplete)
  return;
```

Don't care about the warning.